# Expo AV not updating durationInMilliseconds on some iPhones but working on others

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

When recording audio, `onStatusUpdate` always returns `duration: 0`.

It will still record the audio as evident from being able to save and later listen to the audio.

However, this problem only exists for a specific device. It works properly on most devices.

#### Why this is Strange:

1. It is not an OS problem. Confirmed problem exists for iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.3.1, but no other test devices using iOS 16.3.1.
2. Not a code mis-match problem. After deleting the app from all test devices and re-running the app in release mode from my laptop, the problem remains for iPhone 14 Pro, but none of the other test devices.
3. Not a hardware problem. The problem does not occur when running expo(45.0.0) expo-av (10.2.0)

#### Device With Issue

iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.3.1, expo version 48.0.9 expo-av version 13.2.1

#### Devices Without Issue

iPhone 14 Pro Max, iPad Mini, iPhone 14 Pro Simulator (all iOS 16.3.1)

Has anyone faced this before?